# Matching two column and get values below the matched column

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

I have one Pivot table in column A and one normal table in column D. Pivot table will be updated every month. I would like to match column A values with column D. Then if the values are not existed then the values in Column A must come under the last cell in column D. If the values are matched then no copy and paste.

I need output as shown in image. I used the formula below but it is not working. It is showing circular reference error. I used it on D13.
How can i solve it. Help me

Is that possible in VBA

[image]

Excel formula which i used:

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(MATCH(A2;$D:$D;0));"";A2)
```

Comment: Did you put this formula in `Column "D"`? It was supposed to ask you about circular reference.

Comment: yes. i used it in Column D.

Comment: You are getting a circular reference because you are comparing to the formula you entered.  Try limiting to $D$12 in your formula instead of the whole column.

Comment: I can do that. But for next month the values will be increased. D12 will go to D22. Then i need to change the formula again.

Comment: Even if you manage to recalculate range to check for criteria, you will need to clear blank cells manualy nonetheless.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Using circular reference function:

Go to *File->Options->Formulas*
Under *Calculation options* tick *Enable iterative calculations*
Set maximum of iterations to 1
Input following formula at first blank cell in `Column D`:

```
=IF(COUNTIF($D$2:INDIRECT(ADDRESS(COUNTA(D:D),4)),A2)=0,A2,"")
```

Drag it down, until you have all needed values.
Note you will still have blank cells, it is impossible to delete them within functions' scope.

#### Using VBA module:

```
Option Explicit
Sub AddDict()
    Dim lRow As Long, iCell As Range
    Dim ClmnA As Range, ClmnD As Range
    Dim MySheet As Worksheet, iDict As Object
    '   Your worksheet, change "Test" accordingly
    Set MySheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Test")
    '   Create dictionary object
    Set iDict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    With MySheet
        '   Last row of the Column "A"
        lRow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        '   Range of Column "A" values starting from second row (without header)
        Set ClmnA = .Range("A2:A" & lRow)
        '   Last row of the Column "D"
        lRow = .Range("D" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        '   Range of Column "D" values starting from second row (without header)
        Set ClmnD = .Range("D2:D" & lRow)
    End With
    '   Loop through each cell in Column "D"
    For Each iCell In ClmnD.Cells
        '   Add cell value to dictionary (omitting duplicates)
        iDict(iCell.Value) = iCell.Value
    Next
    '   Loop through each cell in Column "A"
    For Each iCell In ClmnA.Cells
        '   Add cell value to dictionary (omitting duplicates)
        iDict(iCell.Value) = iCell.Value
    Next
    '   Populate Column "D" with dictionary items
    MySheet.Range("D2:D" & iDict.Count + 1) = Application.Transpose(iDict.Items)
End Sub
```

Comment: Can you explain what is 4 means ?

Comment: Sorry for a long wait. 4 is a number of `Column D`

Comment: Ok no problem. I tried this formula. But When i am dragging down it is not working. Do you have any other idea. Is that posibile to do VBA

Comment: @Deepak Worked fine to me, give me a moment, I'll modify the answer.

Comment: @Deepak I've modified the answer, take a look, if possible.

Comment: Thanks for the code. It is almost working. The problem is when i try to change the range it is not working. I change A2 to A4 and D2:D to E4:E. Can you help me, where is the error ?

Comment: @Deepak You can change `A2` to `A4`, there should not be any issues. There is whole other situation with `D2:D`. Notice this line: `MySheet.Range("D2:D" & iDict.Count + 1) = Application.Transpose(iDict.Items)`. I've manualy added `+1` because data starts from second row. In case with `E4:E` in will be `+3`